# Particular integral of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 5\frac{dy}{dx} + 4y = \mathrm{e}^x\ $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the particular integral for the following equation:
$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 5\dfrac{dy}{dx} + 4y = \mathrm{e}^x\ $

So far I have found that $y = A\mathrm{e}^{4x}+B\mathrm{e}^x $.

Then for PI, $y = C\mathrm{e}^x $, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} =C\mathrm{e}^x $, $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=C\mathrm{e}^x $.

But when I tried to substitute this to the equation at the top, the result came out to be $0$. Does this mean $C$ is zero? I was told by my teacher that the answer is not zero and can't seem to find the answer.

Many thanks!

Comment: No. It means that $Ce^x$ is not the PI you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Particular solution should be of the form 
$$
y=Ax\mathrm{e}^x,
$$
as the inhomogeneous term is a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation.

In fact it can be readily shown that $A=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

The particular integral needs to be independent from the solution of the homogeneous equation. Since $e^x$ is one of the homogeneous solutions, it can not be used as the particular integral. You can make a new function that is independent by multiplying by $x$ leading to the form $Cxe^x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't remember that a possible particular solution is $C x e^{x}$, you may try using variation of parameter as I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652362/find-the-form-of-a-second-linear-independent-solution-when-the-two-roots-of-indi/652468#652468).

Cheers!